# Write, clear and run python script from within vim by Shortcut

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, vim, python

I found a way to hit F1-key in a python script in vim and it would clear old shell output for me and run the script by:

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F1> :exec '!clear; python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

And then I found a way to save and run the script by

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <F9> :w<CR>:!python %<CR>
```

But how can I combine all 3 things into one shortcut? So first saving (:w) then !clear and then execute with !python?

Thank you.

Patrick

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bar `|` to combine commands together. From `:help :bar`

```
                            *:bar* *:\bar*
'|' can be used to separate commands, so you can give multiple commands in one
line.  If you want to use '|' in an argument, precede it with '\'.
```

In your case this would be

```
autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <F1> :w \| exec '!clear; python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

(Note the use of `\|`)